# Maple 16 : missing operator or ';'

Tags: maple

First of all, sorry if I have a bad english : i'm french.

Here's my problem : I have the following code :

```
#Méthode de l'interpolation de Hermite
hermite:=proc(x,a,b,n,f)

local i,q,p,pl1,p2,dq,dp1,df,pl2;

#pl = polynôme de lagrange, p = polynôme
q:=t-x[1];

#création du polynôme q (méthode de la double résolution de lagrange)
for i from 2 to n by 1 do
    q:=q*(t-x[i]);
od
dq:=diff(q,t);

#p1 est en fait interp(x,map(f,x),t)
pl1:=interp(x,map(f,x),t);
dpl1:=diff(p1,t);

#on créé les zi, qui sont en réalité f'(xi)
df:=diff(f(t),t);

#on créé p2(xi)
for i from 1 to n by 1 do
p2[i]:=(df(x(k))-dpl1(x[i]))/dq(x[i]);
od

#on créé pl2(t) à partir du polynôme obtenu p2(xi);
pl2:=interp(x,p2,t);

#affichage des résultats
p:=t->pl1+q*pl2;
print("Interpolation de Hermite par double résolution de Lagrange :");
print(plot[p(t),f(t)],t=a..b);

#MANQUE A FAIT LA QUESTION 3.2

end;
```

And I have the following error : `"Error, missing operator or ;"` which says that the problem might be in this exact part `"q:=q*(t-x[i]);",` just before the `x`, but I just can't see why.

Thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. end the procedure with `end proc;`
2. close the 2 loops with a semicolon like `od;`

Should work then